# ZF2: Master/Slave replication with joins

Tags: mysql, zend-framework2

I have two databases: db1 and db2.
I created a slave for db1, called db1-slave.

db1 contains the Analytics table which will have high write rates, low read rates (which is why i created the Master/Slave relationship). I have the Master/Slave feature set and ready to go.

A problem is that when joining with the other database db2 for reading, an error occurs saying that db2 does not exist. It does not exist at the slave layer, and I do not prefer to set it up also for replication (to preserve bandwidth).

```
    $select = new Select();
    $select->from($this->table)
            ->columns(['*', 'count' => new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression('count(app.id)')])
            ->join('app', 'analytics.app_id = app.id', array('*'), 'left')
            ->join(new TableIdentifier('ad', 'db2'), 'ad.id = analytics.event', array('*'))
            ->group('ad.id')->order('ad.id ASC');
```

Can I modify this in a way to enable reading from db1-slave, and reading from db2 on JOINS?